# Reinstalling ONLY Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, reinstall

I just reinstalled my `OS`, and would like to make the process much more efficient and specific.

As an example, currently, `Windows Store` is missing files, and others' suggested fixes failed.
I would like to improve the efficiency of this process (i.e. not have to reinstall files continuously).

Is there a way to only re-install the things that came with `Windows`?

Leaving all apps, data, registry data, etc. alone?

Or am I stuck painfully re-installing, backing up, copying, and so forth?

Comment: Have you tried booting off the Windows 10 media and doing a repair? That is exactly what it does.

Comment: I'm pretty sure I tried that, and it didn't seem to fix my problem earlier. But I'll keep that in mind for next time. That's what I was looking for, after all. Thanks.

Comment: it checks all the windows files and reinstall any missing files and configuration,  leaving all user files and data intact

Comment: You can also try the command `sfc /scannow` which searches for errors in windows dlls and attempts to repair them. It does not rule out that you may still need to reinstall windows. Keep in mind that searching for "Reset Windows" allows you to restore windows to a clean slate, but you will need to install your programs again. Also, you can attempt to create a new user and login with that new user. All programs and files are still there, just your settings are reset.

Comment: Also, take a look at Portable Programs. They are versions of programs that do not need to be installed and can be moved freely from pc to pc, and thus also from windows install to windows install, and keep your settings etc in tact.

Comment: So what command did you use to remove the Windows Store application?  "Is there a way to only re-install the things that came with Windows?" - Use the Reset feature and choose to keep your personal files.  This result in a fresh installation of Windows 10, with your existing user profiles, and only requiring you to install your traditional desktop applications.

Answer (score 0):

Try to Reset windows - go in Star menu -> Settings -> Update & Security -> Recover - then pick Reset this PC. Once you get started you have to choose to save all stuff (like files and etc) you have or not. It is handy option. But still - all apps will be reinstalled, so you must configure them again :/

Good luck :)

Answer (score -1):

Download any Windows 10 ISO. Mount it (select the ISO and click Enter) and run Setup as Admin. This will do a non-destructive install of Windows 10 on a running Windows 10 machine, which should fix the broken parts of the operating system. Then tell Windows Update to "check for updates" to bring the new install up to current state. I've done this, and it works, and does not delete any of my installed programs, files, etc. If you have Home or Pro, the ISO will know which one to install. Yes, Windows 10 ISOs -will- run Setup directly - not necessary to create a bootable USB drive unless you have a dead machine or are creating Windows 10 on a fresh drive.